# Meaning of holomorphic Euler characteristics?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I wonder what holomorphic Euler characteristic $\chi(\mathcal{O}_X)$ of a variety represents. For example, I have seen someone fix $\chi(\mathcal{O}_C)=n$ for a complex curve $C$. What does this mean geometrically? Remember that $\chi(\mathcal{O}_X)$ is defined as the alternating sum
$$
\chi(\mathcal{O}_X)=\sum_{i=0}^{\dim X}(-1)^i\dim \mathrm{H}^i(X,\mathcal{O}_X). 
$$

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you have any [sheaf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_%28mathematics%29) $\mathcal F$ (if it is locally free, it is essentially the same as talking about [vector bundles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle)), then a very important invariant would be the dimension of independent global sections, $h^0(X,\mathcal F):=\dim \Gamma (X,\mathcal F)$, but it turns out that it needs cohomological corrections to be so. Now that is a difficult number to calculate since taking global sections of an [exact sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence) of sheaves is not in general an exact sequence of the global section spaces, for example:
$$0\rightarrow \mathcal F\rightarrow \mathcal G\rightarrow \mathcal H\rightarrow 0,\;\; \text{but} \\ 0\rightarrow \Gamma(X,\mathcal F)\rightarrow \Gamma(X,\mathcal G)\rightarrow \Gamma(X,\mathcal H).$$
This is the beginning of [sheaf cohomology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_cohomology) (which can be built via [derived functors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_functor) and usually computed via [Čech cohomology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%8Cech_cohomology)): the inexactness of the global section sequence is measured by new groups $H^i(X,\mathcal F)$, where $H^0(X,\mathcal F):=\Gamma (X,\mathcal F)$:
$$0\rightarrow H^0(\mathcal F)\rightarrow H^0(\mathcal G)\rightarrow H^0(\mathcal H)\rightarrow H^1(\mathcal F)\rightarrow H^1(\mathcal G)\rightarrow H^1(\mathcal H)\rightarrow H^2(\mathcal F)\rightarrow \cdots\rightarrow 0$$
Thus although you may not be able to compute $\dim H^0(X,\mathcal F)=:h^0(X,\mathcal F)$, there are many techniques and important theorems to compute its Euler-Poincare characteristic $$\chi(\mathcal F):=\sum_{i=0}^{\dim X}(-1)^i\cdot \dim H^i(X,\mathcal F),$$ because  $\chi$ is additive on exact sequences, i.e. $\chi (\mathcal G)=\chi (\mathcal F)+\chi (\mathcal H)$. For example one can prove [Bézout's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem) using two appropriate exact sequences and this previous equations, since the $H^i(\mathbb P^2,\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2}(d))$ can be computed explicitly. The major theorem for computing $\chi$ in general is the [Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirzebruch%E2%80%93Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem) with its many [applications relating the degrees of the variety and of its divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47451/consequences-of-degree-theory/231033#231033).

So you can think of $\chi(\mathcal F)$ as the number of independent sections of the sheaf $\mathcal F$ modulo cohomological correction terms (and it is this number which is an invariant and not just $h^0$). The whole subject of [vanishing theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_theorem) studies results which give the conditions when certain $H^i(X,\mathcal F)=0$ for $i\geq 1$, so that your $\chi$ is as close as possible to your desired dimension (e.g. that is why the defining alternating sum is finite, ending up at least at $\dim X$). Now, $\mathcal O_X$ is the [structure sheaf of the variety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_sheaf), i.e. the collection of regular function rings for every open subset of $X$ with its usual restriction to open subsets. Thus, $\chi (\mathcal O_X)$ measures, up to cohomological corrections, the number of independent global regular/holomorphic functions on your variety $X$, which is a very important invariant. For example the number of independent differential forms of top order, $p_g(X):=\dim H^0(X,\omega_X)$, is called the [geometric genus of $X$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_genus) ($\omega_X$ is a [line bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_bundle) in this case). It is a remarkable theorem that for complex projective algebraic curves (equivalently, compact Riemann surfaces or closed orientable real surfaces) this geometric genus coincides with the [topological genus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_of_topological_surface) $g=p_g$, the number of "doughnut holes" the real surface of the complex curve has. There is another number called the [arithmetic genus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_genus) $p_a$, defined via Hilbert's polynomials, which also coincides for the case of curves $g=p_g=p_a$. Such results and concepts appear in the [Riemann-Roch theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Roch) which gives the value of $\chi (\mathcal L)$ for a line bundle on a curve $X$ in terms of such genera $g$ and the [degree of the associated divisor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140123/how-do-different-definitions-of-degree-coincide/228903#228903) $\deg [\mathcal L]$. Besides, it makes use of a [duality theorem by Serre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre_duality) so that one can express $H^{n-k}(X,\mathcal L)$ in terms of $H^k(X,\omega_X\otimes\mathcal L^\vee)$, and in this case of curves put $\chi (\mathcal L)$ just in terms of dimensions of global sections! 
$$\chi (\mathcal L)=\dim H^0(X,\mathcal L)-\dim H^0(X,\omega_X\otimes\mathcal L^\vee)=\deg [\mathcal L]+1-g.$$
If instead of the one-dimensional sheaves (line bundles) $\mathcal L$, we write the theorem in terms of the [divisors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_%28algebraic_geometry%29) associated to the zero locus of a generic of its sections, $D=[\mathcal L]$, the result is:
$$\chi (D)=h^0(D)-h^0(K-D)=\deg D+1-g.$$
Since $H^0(X,\cdot)=\Gamma (X,\cdot)$ measures the number of independent sections, this Riemann-Roch theorem tells you the following: the number of independent rational/meromorphic functions with zeros and poles at, and bounded by, the divisor $D$, minus the corresponding number but for the divisor $K-D$ (where $K$ is a [canonical divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_divisor), i.e. the generic zero locus of a differential 1-form on the curve) is just the degree of the divisor $D$, plus one, minus the (geometric = topological = arithmetic) genus of the complex algebraic curve. So in this case, if you fix $\chi_C (\mathcal L)=n$ for a curve $C$, you are considering sets of points of zeros and poles, i.e. divisors $D=[\mathcal L]$ given by rational sections of $\mathcal L$, with total fixed degree $\deg D=(g_C-1)+n$. Notice that in algebraic topology, your complex curve $C$ seen as a closed oriented real surface has for any triangulation of $V$ no. of vertices, $E$ no. of edges and $F$ no. of faces a corresponding topological characteristics:
$$\chi_{\text{top.}}(C)=V-E+F=-2(g-1)=-\deg K,$$
which is the degree of a generic canonical divisor on $C$; this $g-1$ also appears in many other applications like [Gauß-Bonnet theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47451/consequences-of-degree-theory/231033#231033). These are remarkable results with very important consequences.

Its generalization to higher dimensional varieties is the cornerstone [Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirzebruch%E2%80%93Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem) which computes $\chi_X (\mathcal F)$ in terms of intersection numbers of characteristic classes of $\mathcal F$ on $X$. Its generalization to compact manifolds in general (even nonalgebraic or with boundary) is the remarkably famous [Atiyah-Singer index theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atiyah%E2%80%93Singer_index_theorem), from which Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch can be obtained for the Dolbeault complex of holomorphic differential operators. I have briefly explained a [bit about this theorem in this other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/252225/4058), where the focus is on computing the Euler characteristic of a sequence of elliptic pseudodifferential operators, i.e. the number of independent solutions to homogeneous partial differential equations up to cohomological corrections, on compact manifolds in terms of their purely topological data.

Comment: This really is one great answer!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you! I love math and explaining it... (hard to stop sometimes).