# Is manifold mapping degree equal to algebraic degree for polynomials?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

If $M$ and $N$ are oriented $n$-manifolds and $f: M \to N$ then the degree of $f$ is given by
$$
\deg f = \sum_{p \in f^{-1}(q)} sign_p f
$$
where $q$ is a regular value and the sign is $+1$ if $f$ is orientation preserving at $p$ and $-1$ if is orientation reversing at $p$. If we identify $\mathbb S^2$ with the one point compactification of the complex plane, then any polynomial in $\mathbb C[X]$ is a smooth map from $\mathbb S^2$ to itself. Does the degree of a polynomial as a map between manifolds coincide the algebraic degree? Equal up to a sign? Easily related?

It's easy to see that they coincide for $f(z)=z^n$. The fundamental theorem of algebra assures that a regular point has exactly the algebraic degree number of preimages, but can the signs of the preimages lower the mapping degree?

Comment: Related question that might interest you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140123/how-do-different-definitions-of-degree-coincide

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, they coincide.  Any polynomial (or indeed any [holomorphic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function)) on the complex plane is orientation-preserving, so all of the "signs" of the preimage are positive.

Note, however, that the maps $f(n)=z^{-n}$ do *not* have negative degree.  These maps are also holomorphic on the sphere, so the degrees are positive (with $z^{-n}$ having degree $n$).  To get negative degree, you have to compose with the complex conjugation map, which has degree $-1$.

Comment: In Guillemin Pollack's book it says that $\operatorname{deg}(z^{m})=m$, where $m<0.$ Is correct that $\operatorname{deg}(z^{-n})=n?$

Comment: @Bungmap Guillemin and Pollack consider the map $z\mapsto z^m$ on the unit cirlce, which indeed has degree $m$ for all integers $m$.  But on the Riemann sphere the map $z\mapsto z^m$ has degree $|m|$.

Comment: Why do we have the difference between Riemann's sphere and unit circle?

Comment: The difference is in how $S^1$ gets its orientation. If you want to use local degrees on $S^2$, you think of $S^1$ as getting a positive orientation as the boundary of a neighborhood of a point. The map $z \mapsto 1/z$ maps the positively oriented $S^1$ around $z=0$ to the positively oriented $S^1$ around $z=\infty$. So degree $+1$. But if you consider this is a map from that circle to itself, then it's a reflection with degree $-1$.